# Generalized lexicographic order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, order-theory

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) I have found this about functions and the lexicographic order, it is basically the statement and I think it is a generalization of the lexicographic order.

Let's define the relationship $\preceq$ in $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ as $f\preceq g$ if $f(n)= g(n)$ or if given $n$ the minimum natural number such that $f(n)\neq g(n)$ you have to $f(n)\leq g(n)$.
Prove that $\preceq$ is a linear order in $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

How can you prove that result? for the case of the lexicographic order it is easy to verify that it is a linear order, but for this case of the more abstract space I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have tried the following:

Reflexivity: Let $f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, we have that $f(n) = f(n)$, then $f \preceq f$.

Antisymmetry: Let $f,g\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, if $f\preceq g$ and $g\preceq f$ it is trivial that $f = g$

Transitivity: Let $f,g,h\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ if $f\preceq g$ and $g\preceq h$, then $f=g$ and $g=h$, then $f=h$ or if given $n$ the minimum natural s.t $f(n)\neq g(n)$ and $g(n)\neq h(n)$ then $f\leq g$ and $g\leq h$ from this we can deduce that $f=h$ or if given $n$ the minimum natural number s.t. $f(n)\neq h(n)$ have $f\leq h$, then $f\preceq h$

It is right? And how can I see that the trichotomy property is fulfilled?

Comment: Write each function as an infinite word (from left to right), and it should make this *a lot* less abstract. Don't try to write the entire function, though, it might collapse the universe.

Comment: To add to what Asaf said, just check that $\preceq$ is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. The first is trivial, and the second is almost as easy; start with them, and then worry about transitivity.

Comment: Adding this to your other recent question, it seems that you're trying to imagine and visualise these objects in order to get the intuition. Don't. You were given the facts, now use the definitions and prove them. You're not asked to explore and come up with facts on your own, that comes later, once you've develop some intuition about this, but for now, just carefully unpack all the definitions. It's not very hard, just a bit tedious.

Comment: Thank you very much @Asaf, yes, the truth is that trying to see what these objects are is somewhat complex, thank you very much for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given proof for transitivety has two mistakes.
Assume f <= g and g <= h.
Case f = g.  Trivally f <= h.
Case g = h.  Trivally f <= h.
Case f < g and g < h.
Exists smallest n with not f(n) = g(n)
and f(n) < g(n).
Exists smallest m with not g(m) = h(m)
and g(m) < h(m).
Case n <= m.  Clearly f < h.
Case m < n.  Show f < h.

Comment: Excuse me, how can the trichotomy property be verified?

Comment: @Haus.  If not f = g, consider the smallest n with not f(n) = g(n).